# Can I do Windows interop story for HTML5?

Tags: html

Is there a way to call C#/.NET/win32 from HTML5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. HTML5 is geared for running in a sand-boxed browser utilizing JavaScript. There is no direct access to the operating system.

You can however use Silverlight for some applications - it has some features into the operating system, but it does not have complete access like Interop or access to the Win32 API.

Comment: So does it mean I can't launch an Exe from a web page, for example?

Comment: That would be a huge security risk. There is Microsoft ClickOnce that might do what you are looking for.